# Edgelist from pandas dataframe with nodes of different colours

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have the following data frame:

```
Src  Dst
A    [A,B]
B    [B,A]
C    [C]
D    [D,E,F]
E    [E,D,F]
F    [F,D,E]
...
```

I would like to generate a network where `Src` is nodes, `Dst` are edges, and where a new column, `Weight`, can assign a different colour (green) to the node which is `A` or D, while the others are all the same (e.g. blue).

I have tried as follows:

## Create a new column Weight

```
nd=["A","D"]
df['Weight'] = np.where(df.Src.isin(nd), 1, 0)
```

The problem is here that I do not know how to assign a colour, so I just tried to assign values 1 for A or D and 0 for all the other values, and separately to change colours.

For the graph, I used the following

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Src', 'Dst')
```

The above line of code does not connect with lines the nodes in Dst, and I cannot understand the reason.
I have found something that might be helpful in assigning colours:

```
   colors=[]
for n in df.Src:
    if n in df.Weight:
        colors.append('g')
    else:
        colors.append('b')

# nodes
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos, node_color = colors)
```

but I have got this error:

> ValueError: 'c' argument has 79 elements, which is inconsistent with
> 'x' and 'y' with size 76.

The image below would be something similar to my expected output (`A` and `D` nodes green, others blue, and links based on `Dst` data; please note that the image below does NOT currently reproduce neither the colour nor the edges expected).

[image]

Could you please help me giving me advice on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do that:

```
df["color"] = "blue"
df.loc[df.Src.isin(["A", "D"]), "color"] = "green"

# The following line is needed because, at least in the way my dataset 
# is created, 'Dst' is not a list but rather a string. 
# For example, Dst of 'A' is the string "[A,B]". Here, 
# I'm converting it to the list ["A", "B"]
# If your data doesn't need this, just comment this line out. 
df["Dst"] = df.Dst.apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(","))

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.explode("Dst"), 'Src', 'Dst')
nx.draw(G, node_color = df.color)
```

The output is:

[image]

Comment: Hi Roy2012. I have opened a new question, if you want to have a look (it is related to this one): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63230886/edgelist-within-pandas-dataframe-to-visualise-using-networkx .Thank you again for your help

Comment: Sure. I'll have a look.

Comment: This is the dataset that has given me this error: `data = [['A', ['A','B']], ['B', ['B','A']], ['C', ['C']] , ['D',['D','E','F']],['E',['E','D','F']],['F',['F','D','E']]]
  

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Src', 'Dst'])`

Comment: See my latest edit. I'll now look at the other question too.

Comment: Hi @Roy2012, I have opened a new question on a similar problem, in case you want to have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63770082/wrong-colors-assigned-to-nodes-in-networkx I have not found a solution yet

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else encounter a plt.scatter colors vs x,y dimension mismatch problem, you can solve it by manually mapping the colors from nodes. My example is a MultiGraph:

```
graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'source', 'target', edge_key='node_type', edge_attr=['edge_id'], 
                         create_using=nx.MultiGraph)

nodes = graph.nodes()
colors = ['blue' if node in old_nodes else 'yellow' for node in nodes]

plt.figure(figsize=(64,48))
nx.draw(graph, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold', node_color=colors)
```