# How to split columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have one question on how to split columns elements into many.
If the dataframe looks like

```
Src  Dst
A    [A,B]
B    [B,A]
C    [C]
D    [D,E,F]
E    [E,D,F]
F    [F,D,E]
...
```

this code

```
df["Dst"] = df.Dst.apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(","))
```

works well.

However, if I have this dataframe:

```
   Src          Dst
x.serm.cool    [x.serm.cool, x.creat.cool]
x.creat.cool   [x.creat.cool, x.serm.cool]
sms.sol.tr     [sms.sol.tr]
bbb.asl.gt     [bbb.asl.gt,cdc.fre.gh,str.alert.jf]
cdc.fre.gh     [cdc.fre.gh, bbb.asl.gt,str.alert.jf]
str.alert.jf   [str.alert.jf, bbb.asl.gt, cdc.fre.gh]
    ...
```

the same does not work. I have tried with

```
df["Dst"]=df["Dst"].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
```

but I got this error:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Could you please explain what differences there are between the two cases?

Thank you

Comment: This more like `explode` not split, the first one is string , 2nd one is list

Comment: Thank you, YOBEN_S. This question is related to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63227703/edgelist-from-pandas-dataframe-with-nodes-of-different-colours/63228939#63228939 Since I had rows with more characters, I thought the problem was in the number of characters or iin the splitting. Cold you please confirm that explode can also work as split does iin that question? I would be interested in using the elements in the list as nodes to link to each other (if in the same list)

Comment: @YOBEN_S, in case you want to have a look, I opened this new question to explain all what I am trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63230886/edgelist-within-pandas-dataframe-to-visualise-using-networkx . I hope the sample can be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your column type with for both dataframe

```
df.Dst.apply(type)

#one of them should be str the 2nd one should be list
```

For the second one we just do `explode`

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.explode("Dst"), 'Src', 'Dst')
```

Comment: @still_learnings your sample data dose not address your problem man ..

Comment: I think the problem is in the data. I got the error message: `ValueError: 'c' argument has 79 elements, which is inconsistent with 'x' and 'y' with size 76`. where `79` is the length of my `Src` including duplicates, while `76` is the length of dataframe not including `Src` duplicates. Thank you so much for your help. I am trying to figure out how to not exclude duplicates since they can be important about the size of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have only these 2 columns for your dataframe.

```
df["newcol1"]=[x[0] for x in df["Dst"]]

df["newcol2"]=[x[1] for x in df["Dst"]]
```

But if you want it to work for a Dataframe with X number of lists in each column, i believe the below code will help you out

```
split_df=df['Dst'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(','.join(x).split(',')))
final_df=pd.concat([split_df,df],axis=1)
```