# Edgelist within pandas dataframe to visualise using networkx

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am having difficulties in representing a dataframe as a network using networkx. The problem seems to be related to the size of dataframe, or, to better explaining, to the presence of duplicates within the dataframe.

My dataset is

```
   Src          Dst
x.serm.cool    [x.serm.cool, x.creat.cool]
x.creat.cool   [x.creat.cool, x.serm.cool]
sms.sol.tr     [sms.sol.tr]
bbb.asl.gt     [bbb.asl.gt,cdc.fre.gh,str.alert.jf]
cdc.fre.gh     [cdc.fre.gh, bbb.asl.gt,str.alert.jf]
str.alert.jf   [str.alert.jf, bbb.asl.gt, cdc.fre.gh]
    ...
x.serm.cool    [x.serm.cool]
```

where `Src`'s values are used as nodes and `Dst` as edges. This means that, for example, `x.serm.cool` has two links, one with itself (but it does not need to consider) and another one with `x.creat.cool`. Another example: `str.alert.jf` has three links: one with itself (but it does not has value); one with `bbb.asl.gt` and another one with c`dc.fre.gh`. All the links are undirected.
I have tried to represent some nodes in the list using different colours:

```
df["color"] = "blue"
df.loc[df.Src.isin(["x.serm.cool", "cdc.fre.gh "]), "color"] = "green"
df["Dst"] = df.Dst.apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(","))

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.explode("Dst"), 'Src', 'Dst')
nx.draw(G, node_color = df.color)
```

but I have got error message due to: `df["Dst"] = df.Dst.apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(","))`.
As explained by *YOBEN_S* in a related question (please see at the bottom of this question), the problem is in considering a list instead of string.
However, when I try as follows:

```
test=["x.serm.cool", "cdc.fre.gh "]
df['color'] = np.where(df.Src.isin(test), "blue", "green")
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.explode("Dst"), 'Src', 'Dst')
nx.draw(G, node_color = df.color)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: 'c' argument has 79 elements, which is inconsistent with 'x' and 'y' with size 76.
```

My original dataset has length `79`, while `76` seems to be the length/size of dataset with no `Src` duplicates. I think that duplicates may be important as they give the node's size, so I would prefer to not remove them from my dataset and network.

Could you please help me to figure this issue out?

**Related questions and answers:**

- [How to split columns in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63230139/how-to-split-columns-in-pandas/63230830#63230830)
- [Edgelist from pandas dataframe with nodes of different colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63227703/edgelist-from-pandas-dataframe-with-nodes-of-different-colours/63228939#63228939)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is because some of the items in your data are duplicated. To solve it, you need to use `drop_duplicates` in the relevant places:

```
df["color"] = "blue"
df.loc[df.Src.isin(["x.serm.cool", "cdc.fre.gh"]), "color"] = "green"
df["Dst"] = df.Dst.apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(","))
df = df.explode("Dst").drop_duplicates()
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'Src', 'Dst')

colors = df[["Src", "color"]].drop_duplicates()["color"]
nx.draw(G, node_color = colors)
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Roy2012. For all the help, support and time provided in helping me. If I comment the line of code `df["Dst"] = df.Dst.apply(lambda x: x[1:-1].split(","))`, I can visualise the network, but without links, but get this further error: `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute 'is_numlike'`.

Comment: Quick question: how could I add nodes' labels to the plot?  I tried with `with_labels = True ` and with `labels = True`, but it has not added any label to the plot.

Comment: Do the following: pos = nx.spring_layout(G) ; nx.draw(G, node_color = colors, pos = pos) ; res = nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos = pos)