# Wrong colors assigned to nodes in networkx

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I am having difficulties in plotting the right colour in a network.
This is my dataset, where users are nodes and values is the user who they are linked to.

```
    User        Val     Color   
92  Laura   NaN      red
100 Laura   John    red
148 Laura   Mike    red
168 Laura   Mirk    red
293 Laura   Sara     red
313 Laura   Sim  red
440 Martyn  Pierre   orange
440 Martyn  Hugh    orange
440 Martyn  Lauren  orange
440 Martyn  Sim     orange
```

I am using the following code:

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'User', 'Val')
labels = [i for i in dict(G.nodes).keys()]
labels = {i:i for i in dict(G.nodes).keys()}
colors = df[["User", "Color"]].drop_duplicates()["Color"]

plt.figure(3,figsize=(30,50)) 
pos = nx.spring_layout(G) 
nx.draw(G, node_color = colors, pos = pos)
net = nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos = pos)
```

where I tried to assign the colors in Color column to the user. My expected output would be:

Laura (node) in red, Martyn (node) in orange and others (John, Mike, Mirk, ...) in green.

Comment: What is your expected result? Did you get any error message?

Comment: HI Jason wong. No, I have not got any error message. The only problem is that colours are wrong

Answer (score 2):

Colors itself are not wrong. You're just trying to assign a color to each couple of nodes which is most likely to be coloring of edges. In that case you need to replace `node_color` keyword with `edge_color`.

```
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'User', 'Val')
colors = df[["User", "Color"]].drop_duplicates()["Color"]

plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3))
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, edge_color = colors, pos = pos)
net = nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos = pos)
plt.show()
```

This is `df` I'm working with:

```
t = '''
User        Val     Color   
92  Laura   NaN      red
100 Laura   John    red
148 Laura   Mike    red
168 Laura   Mirk    red
293 Laura   Sara     red
313 Laura   Sim  red
440 Martyn  Pierre   orange
440 Martyn  Hugh    orange
440 Martyn  Lauren  orange
440 Martyn  Sim     orange'''
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(t), sep='\s+')
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: This is unexpected. This might be a different `df` you were using. Does my updated answer work for you?

Comment: It is, use `node_colors` in that case instead. But this is really important to link them with `G.nodes()` which is 9 nodes in total. So you need to pass a list that contains 9 colors.

Comment: I think it is not clear to me, I am sorry mathfux. What I have tried to do is distinguish some nodes to others. For example: men in blue, women in red and NA in orange. If I had 200 nodes, should I include 100 colours (this is the part that I have not completely understood)? I should be able to get the color corresponding to the user as shown in the top table in my question, but I am not sure if it is doable

Comment: You should include a list of 200 colors (this is an amount of nodes) if you're passing them to `node_colors`. On the other hand, you should include a list of colors that contains the same number of colors as there were edges in your graph if you use `edge_colors`. Consistency can be checked with `len(<node_colors>) == len(G.nodes()` and `len(<edge_colors>) == len(G.edges()`. An error could be caused if that's not right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221102/discussion-between-mathfux-and-still-learning).

Comment: This is unexpected for me too. I'm asked here on chat: "What kind of error is this? Coloring of edges works for dataset updated. Coloring of nodes is not implemented yet by yours." Look at my anser update again.

Comment: The problem is that instead of edges, should be nodes to be colored in red and orange. I would like to have only Laura in red and Martyn in orange. The other nodes can be in blue, green, it would not matter. The edges are difficult to be seen as the nodes are around 200 or more. Your answer would be fine if I look at edges, but unfortunately I am more interested in nodes for a visual perspective

Comment: I'm sorry, SO is not quite right place to ask how to implement a feature. You need to show what you've tried in your post and identify what's the problem better. You need to define a way which you want your nodes to be colored and passed as a list to `node_colors` of length needed.

Comment: I have thought I already implemented actually, since I assigned the right colour to each node in the dataset. What I have tried is to use the column Color to assign for each URL its color as shown in my pandas dataframe. I also defined a way which I want my nodes be coloured (Colour column). What it is not clear is probably how to pass it as a list to node_colors as what I have done does not let me get the right output (and this explain why I asked the question ;) This should follow all the guidelines as the data provided and the code is reproducible. But if it does not, please let me know

Comment: @still_learning No, you didn't assign the right colour to each node in the dataset. Using extra column of `df` doesn't make it because there is usually more nodes than length of this column as in your case. Using remaining collection of colors for second column (named Val) might have solve it. But again, you need to edit your question in that case or try to implement calculation of this collection yourself.

Comment: sorry mathfux, the only colours that I am going to use are 3: red, orange and green (for example). The column in df should be used as a list where to get colours to use within networkx in node_color. I've asked this question since I've not understood what I need to change or edit in my code, and unfortunately it is still not clear.I think it is not an easy question to answer, otherwise I would have received answers which could show how to do it. I think you are right when you say that there is something in Val which are probably causing the issue. But I would like to understand how to fix it.